# R - ggplot2 poor quality of charts generated on Windows

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

Why lines in a chart generated from ggplot2 on Mac looks so smooth and round, but on Windows they look so sharp and edgy. Is there any option to fix that on Windows instead of going to the Apple Store?

For example, chart generated on Mac:
[image]

and a chart generated on Windows:

[image]

**Edit:**

Due to @thestatnoob answer, this is a plot generated from iris dataset on R 3.0.2, RStudio 0.99.486, chart resolution: 640x480.

```
data(iris)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = iris) + 
geom_density(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = ..scaled.., fill = Species), alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that the first graph was generated with a PDF (or other vector graphics) device, while the other was generated (at low resolution) on a PNG or other bitmap device? I can make the same graph look smooth or pixelated on my Mac depending on whether I save it as a PDF or hi-res PNG vs. a low-res PNG.

Comment: Please give the actual code that generated each.

Comment: Also: have a look at anti-aliasing options (for example, using the Cairo package in R will anti-alias lines, making them less jagged.) Anti-aliasing may be on by default on Mac installations http://www.r-bloggers.com/exporting-nice-plots-in-r/

Comment: maybe you figure out how to solve it in the mean time, but I'd try to [save the plot to file](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html) to get a better quality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anti-aliasing options from the Cairo package in R solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to a rendering error rather than anything else. R graphics do look more low res and "edgy". Try plotting the exact same dataset in both OS's with the same settings, e.g. PNG/PS/PDF with identical resolution. If it turns out that the Windows plot doesn't look great, an alternative solution would be to:

- Use RStudio, which is a GUI for R and produces "smooth" graphics, even on Windows
- Use R in a MS PowerShell/command prompt

Comment: I edited my question, added a chart generated from RStudio on Windows.